# Loading a jQuery plugin in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to run a jQuery plugin in the Wordpress. I am trying to have two divs which are exactly the same size. For this I am using [this script](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Equal-Heights).

This works great on the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4bogdmp/), but not so great on my wordpress site.

```
function equalhight(){
wp_enqueue_script(
    'equalhight',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ jQuery.equalHeights.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'equalhight' );



function equaldiv() {
$output="<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.mainblog').equalHeights(true); });
</script>";
echo $output;
}
add_action('wp_head','equaldiv');
```

but the browsers shows errors of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined and Uncaught TypeError: $(...).equalHeights is not a function

Comment: I don't think you should have the space between `/js/ ` and `jQuery.equalHeights.js`. Remove the space and try it again: `/js/jQuery.equalHeights.js`...

Comment: 1) are u sure u include jq into your theme?

2) explore your source - maybe your equaldiv callback runs before jq.

Comment: I've removed the space but still no results. The script is loaded as [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) says.

Comment: Try wrapping your plugin in `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { plugin code here })`. Quote from WP Codex `The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict() mode. This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link. In the noConflict() mode, the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not available`

Comment: Thanks that worked ;)